# jekyll category posts not rendering

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

i've had my personal site running on jekyll for a long while, but i recently noticed my photography page [no longer renders live](http://ryantroyford.com/photo/). i got a new laptop not too long ago and re-installed jekyll, so i suspect it has something to do with jekyll versions/some updated syntax i'm now using incorrectly, as it was working fine before that.

the photo page [is setup to display previews of all the posts in the 'photo' category](https://github.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com/blob/gh-pages/photo/index.html), and the user can then click through to get the full story. looking at the rendered source code and inspecting the elements, this category function is not rendering at all, and no content besides the header & footer is being displayed.

i've been trying to figure out the issue all morning, any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://github.com/ryantroyford/ryantroyford.com/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2016-01-01-photo.md) has the same permalink (/photo) as your page.
Suppressing the post makes it work.

Another way is to have a page photo.html (like your journal.html). You can have /photo.html for your category and /photo for your post.

Comment: you're absolutely right. i had suppressed that post in the past, as i added a "photo" link in the top navigation and thus no longer needed that thumbnail icon in the body. not sure why it showed back up. thanks very much for your help.